# Access my local site with localhost and a custom domain at the same time

Tags: wordpress, nginx, redirect, localhost, hosts

I have a local WordPress site with the custom domain `mysite.local`, but I can't use this custom domain as a Redirect URI with Google APIs. The only accepted way is to use `localhost` instead.

I want to keep the custom domain running, and redirect any traffic to `localhost` to this custom domain, so all the traffic to `mysite.local` and `localhost` will hit my local site (running on Nginx).

Here's what I get when I try to use `mysite.local` as a redirection URI in Google API console:

[image]

See that the `localhost` was accepted, otherwise, it asks to use a valid [top private domain](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/InternetDomainNameExplained#public-suffixes-and-private-domains).

I tried to find a way to do that with `.htaccess` or `/etc/hosts` with no luck.

Comment: `.local` domains and `localhost` are not available to other computers except your own server.  Are these really domains you are trying to use for something?

Comment: What does "can't use this custom domain as a Redirect URI with Google APIs" mean?  Which Google API are you using?  Why are you trying to use this API?  Can you link to its documentation?

Comment: I have added a screenshot to explain what I mean @StephenOstermiller.